# PHP Regex - Remove break line after li

Tags: php, regex

I am building a kind of BBCode for my site, and I currently have the following code:

```
$bbcode = array(
        ...
        '#\[ul\](.*?)\[/ul\]#is' => '<ul>$1</ul>',
        '#\[li\](.*?)\[/li\]#is' => '<li>$1</li>'
    );
```

My problem is that, after the `<li>` it is adding a `<br />`, which is creating a lot of empty space between the list items.

Is there some code I can add in the `[li]` regex, that can ignore/remove the `<br />` that is added after?

Comment: Yes there is, but you would be much better off using a free library for this incredibly common task

Comment: What's wrong with `str_replace()`? `str_replace('<li><br />', '<li>', '<li>'.$1.'</li>')`

Comment: Rather than "building a kind of BBCode for my site" why not just use BBCode and use the existing code for handling BBCode that has already been written, debugged and tested and ships with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$bbcode = array(
    ...
    '#\[li\]\s+(.*?)\[/li\]#is' => '<li>$1</li>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it in two steps (first change with br then without):

```
'#\[li\](.*?)(?:<br />)(.*?)\[/li\]#is' => '<li>$1$2</li>'
'#\[li\](.*?)\[/li\]#is' => '<li>$1</li>'
```

or if br always is after li and nothing else :

```
'#\[li\](?:\s*<br />)?(.*?)\[/li\]#is' => '<li>$1</li>'
```